# dynamically inserting templates in meteor

Tags: meteor

Ok so I've got my template in its own file named myApp.html. My template code is as follows

```
<template name="initialInsertion">
  <div class="greeting">Hello there, {{first}} {{last}}!</div>
</template>
```

Now I want to insert this template into the DOM upon clicking a button. I've got my button rendered in the DOM and I have a click event tied to it as follows

```
Template.chooseWhatToDo.events = {
  'click .zaButton':function(){
     Meteor.ui.render(function () {
       $("body").append(Template.initialInsertion({first: "Alyssa", last: "Hacker"}));
     })
  }
}
```

Now obviously the $("body").append part is wrong but returning Template.initialInsertion... doesn't insert that template into the DOM. I've tried putting a partia {{> initialInsertion}}but that just errors out because I dont have first and last set yet... any clues?
Thanks guys

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is first and last going into a Meteor.Collection eventually?

If not, the simplest way I know is to put the data into the session:

```
Template.chooseWhatToDo.events = {
    'click .zaButton' : function () {
         Session.set('first', 'Alyssa');
         Session.set('last', 'Hacker');
    }
}
```

Then you would define:

```
Template.initialInsertion.first = function () {
  return Session.get('first');
}

Template.initialInsertion.last = function () {
  return Session.get('last');
}

Template.initialInsertion.has_name = function () {
  return Template.initialInsertion.first() && Template.initialInsertion.last();
}
```

Finally, adjust your .html template like this:

```
<template name="initialInsertion">
    {{#if has_name}}
        <div class="greeting">Hello there, {{first}} {{last}}!</div>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

This is the exact opposite solution to your question, but it seems like the "Meteor way".  (Basically, don't worry about manipulating the DOM yourself, just embrace the sessions, collections and template system.)  BTW, I'm still new with Meteor, so if this is not the "Meteor way", someone please let me know :-)

Comment: yeah It think you are right. The session handling is something I'm missing from my app but I guess this is one of the places where it plays its role. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 14):

## In meteor 1.x

```
'click .zaButton':function(){
   Blaze.renderWithData(Template.someTemplate, {my: "data"}, $("#parrent-node")[0])
 }
```

#### In meteor 0.8.3

```
'click .zaButton':function(){
   var t = UI.renderWithData(Template.someTemplate, {my: "data"})
   UI.insert(t, $(".some-parrent-to-append"))
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

I think you may want to use Meteor.render within your append statement.  Also, note that if you are passing data into your Template, then you must wrap Template.initialInsertion in an anonymous function, since that's what Meteor.render expects.  I'm doing something similar that seems to be working:

```
Template.chooseWhatToDo.events = {
  'click .zaButton':function(){
    $("body").append(Meteor.render(function() {
      return Template.initialInsertion({first: "Alyssa", last: "Hacker"})
    }));
  }
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: is that a jQuery selector?

Comment: yes, that's a jquery selector, and while this method works, it's not truly the Meteor way - see Josh's answer for a better approach

Answer (score 1):

Many answer here are going to have problems with the new Blaze engine. Here is a pattern that works in Meteor 0.8.0 with Blaze.

```
//HTML
<body>
  {{>mainTemplate}}
</body>

//JS Client Initially
var current = Template.initialTemplate;
var currentDep = new Deps.Dependency;

Template.mainTemplate = function()
{
  currentDep.depend();
  return current;
};

function setTemplate( newTemplate )
{
    current = newTemplate;
    currentDep.changed();
};

//Later
setTemplate( Template.someOtherTemplate );
```

More info in this seccion of [Meteor docs](http://docs.meteor.com/#deps_dependency)